# Target sites hidden behind the dialog box in the moderator migration dialog on Chrome/Android

Tags: bug, design, moderator-tools, mobile-web, mobile-chrome

In the moderator version of the “Closing>Off-Topic>Migration” dialog, we can enter an arbitrary target site, selected with a combo list box.

On Chrome 66.0.3359.158 on Android 7.1.2, the list is hidden behind the dialog. You can just see the bottom peeking out. This makes it impossible to select a site unless enough other completions come before it alphabetically.

[image]

Comment: I replicated this on Chrome on iOS as well.  Does not happen on Safari.  Chrome 66.0.3359.122 iOS11.3.1

Comment: Reproduced on the mobile theme. Works fine in the full theme.